# Create dynamic cell block reference in excel formula

Tags: excel, dynamic, range

I am at a loss as to how to create a dynamic cell block reference in an Excel formula. As a simple example, if I have 5 `id`'s with `scores` per block and I needed to rank the scores within each block, what would be the easiest way to create formulas to do this? I am aware that you can create the formulas in the first 5 cells using relative references (i.e. `=RANK.EQ(B#, B2:B6)`), copy those cells, and paste in the range that highlights the 15 cells.

[image]

Comment: Is the size of your blocks consistent throughout? Finding pretty hard to think of a way to program around the fact that you have repeated ID's. Would be easier if the block was defined by a unique identifier rather than the position on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the blocks are 5 rows every time, then you can create ongoing 5-row-blocks in column `B` using `INDEX` the following way:

[image]

Formula in helper column `F` beginning in `F2` downwards:

```
=2+INT((ROW(A1)-1)/5)*5
```

Formula in helper column `G` beginning in `G2` downwards:

```
=2+4+INT((ROW(A1)-1)/5)*5
```

Formula in `C2` downwards:

```
=RANK(B2,INDEX(B:B,F2):INDEX(B:B,G2))
```

Formula in `D2`downwards (without helper columns):

```
=RANK(B2,INDEX(B:B,2+INT((ROW(A1)-1)/5)*5):INDEX(B:B,2+4+INT((ROW(A1)-1)/5)*5))
```